# (Algebraically) prove $a^x$ is an increasing function

Tags: calculus, functions, exponential-function

How to prove $a^x$ (for $a>1$) is an increasing function, independently of $\int_1 ^x \frac{dx}{x}$ or $\operatorname{Ln}(x)$. Is there a way to algebraically prove $(x_1>x_2 \implies a^{x_1}>a^{x_2})$ with as little reference possible to calculus?

I understand we technically define $a^x$ through $\operatorname{Ln}(x)$, but is there a different algebraic perspective that we can give to $a^x$? At least for the rational numbers (since we need the $\operatorname{Ln}(x)$-based definition for defining irrational powers.)

Comment: HINT:  Show that for $a>1$ and $x>0$, $a^x>1$.

Comment: if $x_1-x_2=\epsilon>0$, then $a^{x_1}=a^{x_2}a^{\epsilon}$, and if $a>1$ then $a^\epsilon>1$

Comment: @j.w.tanner One needs to show algebraically that $a^x>1$ for all $a>1$ and $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $a^{x_1}=a^{x_2}a^{x_1-x_2}$

Answer (score 0):

No, we *don't* need to use logarithms to define $a^x$ for $a>0$. You can define it first when $x$ is rational: if $x=\frac mn$, with $m\in\Bbb Z$, and $n\in\Bbb N$, then $a^x=\sqrt[n]{a^m}$. It is easy to see that this makes sense, that is, that if $\frac mn =\frac pq$, then $\sqrt[n]{a^m}=\sqrt[q]{a^p}$. Then, for an arbitrary $x$, you can define $a^x$ as follows:  take a sequence $(q_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of rational numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}q^n=x$ and define $a^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{q_n}$. It can be proved that this definition doesn't depend upon the choice of the sequence $(q_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{q_n}$ always exists.

Now, if $a>1$, if $m_1,m_2\in\Bbb Z$ and if $n\in\Bbb N$, it is easy to prove that$$\frac{m_1}n<\frac{m_2}n(\iff m_1<m_2)\implies a^{m_1/n}<a^{m_2/n}.$$So, the restriction of $x\mapsto a^x$ is strictly increasing. And now it's not hard to prove that if $x,y\in\Bbb R$ are such that $x<y$ and that if $q\in(x,y)\cap\Bbb Q$, then$$a^x<a^q<a^y.$$

Answer (score 0):

So you asked to show that $a^{q} > a^{p}$ for rationals $q>p$.

Divide both sides by $a^{p}$. You want to show, $a^{q-p} > 1$. You can get a common denominator d for p and q and use the fact that $x^{n}$ is increasing in $[1,\infty)$ for natural number n to get that $a^{q-p} > 1$ if and only if $a^{qd-pd} > 1$. Now it suffices to show that $a^{n}> 1$ for a natural number n if $a>1$. You will use the fact that $x^{n}$ is increasing in $[1,\infty)$ for natural number n here again.